# Make locally deployed module join the process on integration environment easily

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, configuration, forward

Our application has different modules deployed under many tomcats ondifferent physical machines. And we have an Apache proxy (mod_proxy) which forwards the client request to associated machine base on the context path. For example: http://dev.appserver/market/doSomeThing.htm will be forwarded to the tomcat which deploys "market" module. And then the processing inside the "market" module can call the services of other modules also through the Apache proxy to make the full business process.

To ease developing of developers, we want some requests through the Apache be forwarded to developer local PC if the session content their username and their username is configured to be forward in the database. Here is the simple code to demonstrate the idea:

```
forwardProcedure 
{    

    username = getUserName(session); // ex: Alex
    contextPath = getContextPath(request); // ex: /market

    toForwardUrl = getConfiguredForwardedUrl(username, contextPath); // get from    database or whatever;
    if (isNotEmpty(toForwardUrl )){
            forwardTo(toForwardUrl) ;  // forward to local pc of developers        
    } else {
            forwardToIntegrationServer(); // as normal.
    }
}
//
```

Could you please give me any idea of tool to configure this? The integration environment is Unix, and developer PCs use Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is that "apache proxy" thing? Apache HTTPD mod_proxy? or some custom application?

Comment: Yes, it is "mod_proxy". I updated it in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How can Apache get the session? The session is on tomcat server, not on Apache.

This need an external rewriteing program. That is, a program that read a variable and stuff and return another url.

If you really want to try the external rewriter approach, read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap and search for "External Rewriting Program". 
 Use the `[P]` flag to route to mod_proxy.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out and give the feedback later.